# N-Channel Mosfet has full Voltage on all Pins (IRFZ44N)

Tags: mosfet, switching, ac-dc

I recently wanted to use a [IRFZ44N N-Channel Mosfet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0025/0900766b80025d94.pdf) (up to 50V) to control a 50 LED Panel with a current of 35V.

The Panel itself uses 230V AC which goes to a rectifier (?) which outputs 35V DC and powers the LEDs successfully.

I then cut the cable going to the negative terminal of the rectifier, connected the part coming from the LEDs to the Drain and the rectifier to Source.

[image: Photo of the setup]

**Problems I have and things I found out:**

- When I power the lamp, I can't control the state of the LEDs (LEDs always on)
- When I measure the power, all 3 Pins (Gate, Drain, Source) measure the full 35V (full output of the rectifier)
- When I tested the Mosfet with 3v pins from my Raspberry Pi, it worked so I guess the Mosfet itself is not broken. Also tested 3 of the same Mosfets all with the same results
- I added a 10kOhm resistor between the gate and the source. It didn't change anything and the LEDs stayed on
- The Mosfet itself is rated for 50V so it sould be able to handle my 35V

I am obviously missing something, but what?

Comment: Seems that your PSU is in series with the FET. Pretty hard to tell how you connected it considering that it is a black blob...

Comment: Post the schematic, please.  (Nobody should be chasing the wires just to figure out what you are trying to do there.)

Comment: First you need to add a schematic, then you need to change your first sentence: 'with a current of 35V'. Did you mean voltage of 35V? Or current of 35A?

Comment: I didn't do anything to the black blob, it came with the board. Will add some schematics

Comment: Is that a metal box and is the black inlet mains power? If yes, then you have got yourself a deathtrap!

Comment: It's a plastic case but yes these chinese things are deathtraps

Answer (score 3):

I could not understand how you connected the MOSFET and LED load. Here's how you should connect:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNaeKk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that Gate Drive signal should have a peak voltage of at least 10V for proper operation.

Comment: You're right the FET is upside down , with the drain to the negative wire.